# binding resize function to images upon loading

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, image-resizing, function-binding

I've been working with twitter bootstrap carousel, and I've written my own image resize function so that images are proportionally resized to the window size. I've also implemented the lazy load for images so that images are only loaded when its the active current slide. So my problem is, how do I bind my resize function to each carousel item when it becomes active?

HTML:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <!-- Carousel items -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="active item" id="item1"> 
      <img src="img1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="item2">
      <img lazy-src="img2">
    </div>
      <div class="item" id="item3">
        <img lazy-src="img3">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Carousel nav -->
  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

My image resize JS:

```
$.fn.imagefit = function(options) {
    var fit = {
        all : function(imgs){
            imgs.each(function(){
                fit.one(this);
                })
            },
        one : function(img){
            var winRatio = parseInt($(window).width()) / parseInt($(window).height());
            var imgRatio = parseInt($(img).width()) / parseInt($(img).height());

            //If imgRatio > winRatio, image is proportionally wider than the resolution ratio for window
            if(imgRatio > winRatio){
                // Fit to width
                $(img).width($(window).width());
                $(img).height(parseInt($(img).width())/imgRatio);
            } else {
                // Fit to height
                $(img).height($(window).height());
                $(img).width(parseInt($(img).height())*imgRatio);

            }
        }
    };

    this.each(function(){
            var container = this;

            // store list of contained images (excluding those in tables)
            var imgs = $('img', container).not($("table img"));

            // store initial dimensions on each image 
            imgs.each(function(){
                $(this).attr('startwidth', $(this).width())
                    .attr('startheight', $(this).height())
                    .css('max-width', $(this).attr('startwidth')+"px");

                fit.one(this);
            });
            // Re-adjust when window width is changed
            $(window).bind('resize', function(){
                fit.all(imgs);
            });
        });
    return this;
};
```

I've tried this, but the method wan'st even invoked

```
    $("#item1").bind("load", function(){
    ("#item1").imagefit(); 
    });
```

I've also tried this, but it broke the carousel as item2,3 are not shown after becoming active item, their width is set to 0

```
   $(window).load(function(){
     $('#item1, #item2, item3').imagefit();
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have errors

```
$("#item1").bind("load", function(){
  ("#item1").imagefit(); // no $ 
});
```

so

```
$("#item1").bind("load", function(){
  $(this).imagefit();
});
```

and here

```
$(window).load(function(){
   $('#item1, #item2, item3').imagefit(); // #item3
});
```